# L1 cache latency measure inside kernel - cache misses one time in two

Tags: caching, cpu, latency

I try to measure my L1(instruction) cache latency.(32KB, 8-way,64B size line)

To do that I wrote a kernel module :

the idea is:

```
1. I disable interrupts(cli)
2. I work with only one cpu with only one core : i do that with 'maxcpus=1' in grub.
3. I fill the L1 instruction cache and I measure latency with rdtsc:
    3a : rdtsc
    3b : fill set 0
    3c : rdtsc and compute the difference between this step and the step 3a
    3d : repeat for all set! 
4. I enable interrupts(sti)
```

I do about 1000 measures. the 900th give me :

```
set 0 :  228 
set 1 :  54 
set 2 :  42 
set 3 :  150 
set 4 :  42 
set 5 :  150 
set 6 :  42 
set 7 :  144 
set 8 :  42 
set 9 :  144 
set 10 :  42 
set 11 :  144 
set 12 :  42 
set 13 :  144 
set 14 :  36 
set 15 :  144 
set 16 :  42 
set 17 :  150 
set 18 :  42 
set 17 :  150 
set 18 :  42 
set 19 :  150 
set 20 :  42 
set 21 :  144 
set 22 :  42 
set 23 :  150 
set 24 :  42 
set 25 :  156 
set 26 :  42 
(...)
```

So I guess my L1 cache latency is 42...

But as you can see it seems there is a cache miss one time in two.

So my question is where does these cache misses come from? (for remember i disabled interrupts)

I expected nearly constant time after the second measure but it seems i'm wrong.

Also I would like to measure L2 caches latency. Do you think i can apply the same method?

thank you

EDIT :

the code I use to fill and measure the cache was found at http://www.iacr.org/archive/ches2010/62250105/62250105.pdf.

you find find the C/asm code at http://pastebin.com/SeZBwgnK

you can find the Makefile at http://pastebin.com/dCtntswM

EDIT 2 :
I modified the previous code : you can find it at (1) http://pastebin.com/X5LZUtVL

I just tried to measure the latency of  the last set inside the L1 cache(set number 63).
In order to preventing the branch prediction I jump randomly over RAM "line" wich are all inside the set 63: 
Instead of doing jumps by step of 64 I do it randomly(i don't care about others sets):
jmp L63 --> jmp L447 ---> jmp L255 ---> jmp L127 ---> jmp L383 ---> jmp L319 ---> jmp L191 --> jmp L511

instead of:
jmp L63 --> jmp L127 ---> jmp L191 ---> jmp L255 ---> jmp L319 ---> jmp L383 ---> jmp L447 --> jmp L511

but doing that will cause misprediction for each jmp doesn't it?

concerning out-of-order, i now use mfence before rdtsc.
Also i measure the time for "mfence;rdtsc" with a program (still a kernel module with interrupts disabled). you can found it at (2)http://pastebin.com/EQVPA3iA which mesure how long are these instrutions.
I do this measure many time and the output of (2) give me "(...)56,60,60,60,60,60,60,56,60(...)" .
there is 4 cycles of difference where does it come from? On average these instructions takes 58 cycle.

now I start the kernel module (1) which give me : "(...)102,108,102,108,102,(...)"
there is 6 cycles of difference(instead of more than 144-42=102 from the first version of my program but there is still a difference one time in two) where does it come from? on averge L1 cache access with "mfence;rdtsc" give me 105 cycles.
So without "mfence;rdtsc" L1 cache access is 105-58=47
maybe because of misprediction?

Comment: A description is nice, but we have no way to know if you really do what you say unless you supply some code. It seems like you're measuring the time over a single read operation instead of measuring several ones and amortizing.

Comment: As @Leeor hinted, you are more measuring the latency of rdtsc. A quick googling (`rdtsc latency`) found [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/305287): "rdtsc does not have this sort of granularity.
For best results, make sure you have at least ~1,000 clocks worth of instructions between consecutive rdtsc calls."

Comment: @Paul : I agree but they used rdtsc on this article : http://www.iacr.org/archive/ches2010/62250105/62250105.pdf and it seems they have results.

Comment: @Leeor : hum you're right i'm sorry! I edit my message to include the code i use. I will give more later(still working on it)

Comment: Can you provide the listing file or an objdump to see if the labels are properly aligned? Also, in general, the branch predictors today are fairly clever in predicting code accesses ahead, it's quite possibly be helping you in some of the lines

Comment: I only glanced at the article, but they used an in-order Atom which may have less and more consistent overhead in reading the counter than a high-performance out-of-order core. *Are you using an in-order core?* The article does not appear to give any data on the timings of L1 hit and L1 miss (3 vs. c.18 cycles for Atom, BTW) merely indicating that they were detectably different. Even with no counter-read overhead, it *looks* like you would actually be measuring correctly predicted branch taken latency which is not the same as Icache latency. Also, 42 cycles is too long even for L2 latency.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton @Leeor : I add two pastebin for the code in my message. the `objdump -t hello-1.ko` give the result at http://pastebin.com/QQ6Zgp6M . it seems all is well aligned because if you do 0xAnAddress modulo 0x40 (0x40=64) you get 0.  this is the first time I do these kind of measures so i guess you're write when you say 42 is too long but for now i don't care about that and i report this problem for later. About in-order/out-or-order i think my cpu(celeron 1000m) is in-order but i'm not sure(maybe a linux file?) so i tried to serialize with rdtscp but it crach, i don't know why yet.

Comment: Also I don't understand the role of the branch predictor an how it can affect my results (i didn't think of that before) can you elaborate?

Comment: Basically, every cycle the branch predictor could predict the next chunk to fetch. As long as all the targets fit in the branch target buffer, such a loop would have perfect prediction and fetch a new jump instruction each cycle. The Icache access is pipelined, so as long as a correct new address is presented each cycle, there will not be any bubble and each fetch will appear to take one cycle because the core does not wait for the fetch to complete before starting the next fetch. The Celeron 1000M is an Ivy Bridge, uses out-of-order execution. Ivy Bridge also has a micro-op cache ...

Comment: The micro-op cache is kind of like an L0 instruction cache which reduces energy use and the branch misprediction penalty (on a micro-op cache hit) and removes the template and width constraints of fetching from the instruction cache (I think Ivy Bridge is limited to 16B fetch from the Icache and a decoding template that can decode up to four instructions with the first decoding into as many as four micro-ops and each successive instruction decoder only supporting one micro-op with fusion making this a bit more complex; the micro-op cache can provide in the best case 32B worth of code/cycle).

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton thank you for all these precisions. what do you mean by "template" and "width constraints"?

Comment: I add "EDIT 2" in my message for the modification i have done. but my measurement seems still too long... do you have ideas?

Comment: x86 instructions can be relatively difficult to decode. To limit design complexity, it is common for the decoders to only support very complex decode in the first instruction. E.g., the Pentium Pro could decode three instructions but only the first could decode into more than one µop (and any instruction decoding into more than 3 µops used a ROM table), so it had a 3-1-1 "template". If the second instruction fetched decodes into 2 µops (excluding some µop fusion cases), then that becomes the first instruction decoded in the next cycle, reducing decode throughput. Limited fetch width ...

Comment: ... can also reduce the rate at which instructions are decoded. Commonly, an *aligned* 16-byte chunk is fetched. A branch target in the middle of such a chunk could only fetch 8 bytes of instructions which is unlikely to have four instructions. Even a full 16 bytes might not be enough to hold four instructions. This is what I meant by "width constraints". The µop cache is limited by *32* byte (in memory) aligned chunks (twice the size) but is not limited by decode template constraints. David Kanter's [article on Sandy Bridge](http://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/4/) might be of interest.